# How to load the latest version of google maps on mobile using phonegap?

Tags: android, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to use google maps on mobile phones, and I am using phonegap framework for that. below is the example code I am using to get the google maps on android phone. but it is of the version 3.8 and when I try to load the latest version 8.1.0 it shows a blank screen. So need help to go in right direction in using google maps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Map</title>

<link href="css/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var marker;
var infowindow;
var watchID;

$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    //for testing in Chrome browser uncomment
    //onDeviceReady();
});

//PhoneGap is ready function
function onDeviceReady() {
    $(window).unbind();
    $(window).bind('pageshow resize orientationchange', function(e){
        max_height();
    });
    max_height();
    google.load("maps", "3.8", {"callback": map, other_params: "sensor=true&language=en"});
    map();
}

function max_height(){
    var h = $('div[data-role="header"]').outerHeight(true);
    var f = $('div[data-role="footer"]').outerHeight(true);
    var w = $(window).height();
    var c = $('div[data-role="content"]');
    var c_h = c.height();
    var c_oh = c.outerHeight(true);
    var c_new = w - h - f - c_oh + c_h;
    var total = h + f + c_oh;
    if(c_h<c.get(0).scrollHeight){
        c.height(c.get(0).scrollHeight);
    }else{
        c.height(c_new);
    }
}

function map(){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.17, 23.76);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
      streetViewControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoomControl: true
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
        //get geoposition once
        //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error, { maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
        //watch for geoposition change
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success, geo_error, { maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });   
    }); 
}

function geo_error(error){
    //comment
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

function geo_success(position) {

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    map.setZoom(15);

    var info = 
    ('Latitude: '         + position.coords.latitude          + '<br>' +
    'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '<br>' +
    'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '<br>' +
    'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '<br>' +
    'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '<br>' +
    'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '<br>' +
    'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '<br>' +
    'Timestamp: '         + new Date(position.timestamp));

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    if(!marker){
        //create marker
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map
        });
    }else{
        //move marker to new position
        marker.setPosition(point);
    }
    if(!infowindow){
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: info
        });
    }else{
        infowindow.setContent(info);
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }); 
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Main Page-->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="main">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>RealTrac</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h3>Select the application</h3>
            <a data-role="button" href="#jnytimetracker">Journey-Time Tracker</a>
            <a data-role="button" href="#qtimetracker">Queue-Time Tracker </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- First Page End -->

    <div data-role="page" id="jnytimetracker">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Map Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 0;">
            <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <h4>Map Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

THanks

Comment: `$(document).on("pageshow"` not `$(window)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on  the google map on my mobile website . And its based on JQuery mobile . Here is what worked for me

This is the most common problem in JQM. I totally agree with @Omar about the solution  .

**Cause of the problem**

The JQM uses script to layer divs over your normal div to make it more enrich and look better
So when you initialize the `google map` these hidden layer causes the problem to show it completely

Most of the time as I have researched in **Google** that the map is shown in the upper left corner of the window :).

**Easy fix**
This one goes only for JQM pages

```
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#map", function() {



});
```

Just put your google map code inside the above code what it does is that the map will load only after all the `divs` have been loaded . Please see the event [`pageshow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) in JQM website.

**My Script** Look something like this

```
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#map-page", function() {
    <?php $coordenadas=explode(',',$fila['Googlemap']);?>

   var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $coordenadas[0];?>','<?php echo $coordenadas[1];?>'); 

   $('#map-canvas').height( $(window).height() - $('#head1').height());
    drawMap(defaultLatLng); // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support
     //var latlng = marker.getPosition();
    function drawMap(latlng) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: latlng,
            streetViewControl:true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Greetings!"
        });
        // this is our gem
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter(center); 
        }); 
}       
});
```

Just change the `#map` selector to the id of the page where the map has to be loaded .

Hope I have helped you or others who have been facing the same problem :)

Thanks & Regards

Comment: how about the `#head1`?